# For give permutation $\sigma\in S_{13}$ solve equation $x^3=\sigma$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

We have this permutation 
$$\sigma =\left({\begin{array}{*{20}c}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13\\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 11 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 10 & 9 & 12 & 4 & 6 & 7\end{array}}\right)\ $$

Find $x^3=\sigma\in S_{13}$

The cycles are (1 3)(2)(4 11)(5)(6 8 10 12)(9)(13 7)

Comment: So, what are the cycles of $\sigma$?

Comment: The cycles of $\sigma$ are determined by the permutation.

Comment: So how they are gonna help me? (1 3)(2)(4 11)(5)(6 8 10 12) (13 7)

Comment: @Alin You forgot the cycle $(9)$

Comment: @Peter, yeah I saw a little bit later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The permutation with the cycles $(1\ 3)(2)(4\ 11)(5)(6\ 12\ 10\ 8)(9)(13\ 7)$ does the job.

You only have to invert the $4$-cycle. The other cycles remain. You can also take the cycle $(2\ 5\ 9)$ to get another solution.

Comment: How you got to these solutions? If $x^3$ = $(1\ 3)(2)(4\ 11)(5)(6\ 8\ 10\ 12)(9)(13\ 7)$ then we can write $x = x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5 x_6 x_7$ (composition between these)? Not sure what's your approach.

Comment: The $1$-cycles anf the $2$-cycles satisfy $x^3=x$.